# How to store multidimensional array in mysql using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

This question use to make me think what should i use, what will be more efficient?
so finally i better to choose ask it one time. it may be kind of stupid.

here is my question

I have a multidimensional array

```
$guests = [
        [
            "adult" => 2,
            "childAge" => [4, 6, 2],
        ],
        [
            "adult" => 3,
            "childAge" => [5, 7],
        ]
    ];
```

I have to store this array in db, to do that i have two type of approach

1. simply make a table with column name room_guests and store data using json_encode() method and it is easy. so i think it right way to do that or just a cheat.

   ```
    $roomGuest = new RoomGuestModel;
    $roomGuest->room_guest = json_encode($guests);
    $roomGuest->save();
   ```
2. Here i think i just make two table

   Table_1 name "room_guest" and it has a column name "adult"

   Table_2 name "child_age" and it has columns name "room_guest_id" and "age"

   **Table**

   ```
    room_guests              child_age
   +-----------+     +-----------------------+
   | id| adult |     | id|room_guest_id| age |
   +-----------+     +-----------------------+
   | 1 |   2   |     | 1 |     1       |  4  |
   | 2 |   3   |     | 2 |     1       |  6  |
   |   |       |     | 3 |     1       |  2  |
   |   |       |     | 4 |     2       |  5  |
   |   |       |     | 5 |     2       |  7  |
   +-----------+     +-----------------------+
   ```

   store date using loop

   Like

   ```
   foreach ($guests as $guest) {
       $roomGuest = new RoomGuestModel;
       $roomGuest->adult = $guest->adult;
       $roomGuest->save();

       foreach ($guest->childAge as $age) {
           $childAge = new ChildAgeModel;
           $childAge->room_guest_id = $roomGuest->id;
           $childAge->age = $age;
           $childAge->save();
       }
   }
   ```

but i have no idea what is the best approach

if you have better idea to do that. so please share.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships specifically the "Inserting & Updating Related Models" section.